# HTML validation warning: <form> lacks "action" attribute (action is needed)

Tags: html, forms

I'm using Firefox plugin to validate html errors on the page. It displays a warning:

> An HTML tag has a mandatory attribute, but this attribute is missing.
>
> Example:
>
> - not good: `<form>`
> - good: `<form action="my_action.jsp">`

Actually I put the `<form></form>` tags to give a name to use it as a parameter for javascript function.

The code looks like:

```
<form name="items">

<select name="selectitem" onchange="displayfunc(this.form)">
<option value="1">one</option>
...
<option value="8">eight</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Everything works fine, but that warning.. Should I fix it? If yes, then how?

BTW, FF displays *"`<form>` lacks "action" attribute"* warning on the stackoverflow page as well. I've found a similar thread [required attribute “action” not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933966/required-attribute-action-not-specified), but I'm still not sure what to do if there is no `action=""` for the form.

Comment: I just don't use the form tag... :) (for singular select fields). You can use a div instead for the ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want users to be able to submit the form, then you shouldn't be using the form element. Use something like `<div id="items"></div>` instead to contain your input items.

BTW, just because another website does something that violates standards doesn't mean you should. :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you will not submit your form, you can set `action` to pretty much everything you want to.

`<form action="#">` is the shortest option.